# C++ Visual Studio 2010 C4717 compiler warning in one part of code but not in another

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, warnings

These six methods (really three, the ones that actually throw the warning are the non-const versions) are causing a C4717 (functions recursive on all paths) warning yet the method following these do not (exactly the same that I can tell...). *What am I missing that is causing the warning for these but not the other one?*

Warning-generating methods:

```
template<class T>
const QuadTreeNode<T>* QuadTree<T>::GetRoot() const {
    return _root;
}


template<class T>
QuadTreeNode<T>* QuadTree<T>::GetRoot() {
    return static_cast<const QuadTree<T> >(*this).GetRoot();
}

template<class T>
const int QuadTree<T>::GetNumLevels() const {
    return _levels;
}

template<class T>
int QuadTree<T>::GetNumLevels() {
    return static_cast<const QuadTree<T> >(*this).GetNumLevels();
}

template<class T>
const bool QuadTree<T>::IsEmpty() const {
    return _root == NULL;
}


template<class T>
bool QuadTree<T>::IsEmpty() {
    return static_cast<const QuadTree<T> >(*this).IsEmpty();
}
```

Non-Warning-generating method:

```
template<class T>
const Rectangle QuadTreeNode<T>::GetNodeDimensions() const {
    return _node_bounds;
}

template<class T>
Rectangle QuadTreeNode<T>::GetNodeDimensions() {
    return static_cast<const QuadTreeNode<T> >(*this).GetNodeDimensions();
}
```

Comment: That warning is buggy and reports false positives. See [this bug report](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/522094/) for more details.

Comment: @ildjarn: So...will it just go away? Is there a way to trick the compiler?

Comment: It's buggy, so all bets are off. Personally, if I knew the warning was incorrect, I would just suppress it.

Comment: Note that it doesn't make sense to define non-`const` versions that return non-`const` `bool` or `int` results.

Comment: Agreed with @Neil. Indeed, it doesn't make sense to ever return objects by `const` value at all -- with primitive types it makes no difference (the const-ness is dropped), and with class types it inhibits move semantics. Only when returning references/pointers should `const` come into play.

Comment: Compiler throws redefinition errors otherwise.

Comment: As ildjarn says, you only need both versions when you're dealing with references or pointers. For example, `template<class T> bool QuadTree<T>::IsEmpty() const { return _root == NULL; }` suffices.

Comment: @ildjarn I'll have to remember that above the move semantics; I've not actually used a new enough compiler yet!

Comment: By any chance could you post the definitions to QuadTreeNode and QuadTree? I was going to attempt to solve the compiling errors.

Comment: @josephthomas: Sorry, they've since been deleted. I've decided to have the user roll their own. The implementations of a quadtree are too specific to go into a general game engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by [ildjarn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/636019/ildjarn), the is an [acknowledged](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/522094/) bug with the warning. If you look at the code at the most basic usage similar of your code, there is no warning with the following (and is not recursive).

```
class A
{
public:
    bool IsEmpty()
    {
        return static_cast<const A>(*this).IsEmpty();
    }

    bool IsEmpty() const
    {
        return true;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A whatever;
    whatever.IsEmpty();

    return 0;
}
```